# Database watcher for mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

How to trigger mule application when the value of the row in a database gets updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you pls explain your scenario ... do you need to trigger a Mule flow when a particlar row get updated or any row ?

Comment: I am uploading a file into the database via web service. It will take some time to process the file and completing the processing. After the processing is completed the data base status will change to completed. At that time I have to initiate the Mule application.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define whether a row has been updated. However a good starting point is poll and watermarks.

Poll allows you to poll a resource such as a database connector with a particualr SQL SELECT query and watermarks allows you store tracking info such as the the last 'id' processed or 'lastupdated' column of a databse for example.

Some links with examples:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Poll+Reference#PollReference-PollingforUpdatesusingWatermarks

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/data-synchronizing-made-easy-with-mule-watermarks/